# Rails - manipulate UI data with a button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two Listboxes (select_tag) containing values and I would to create a button that transfer a value from one to the other.
I would like the user to be able to click on one value or more and move them to the other list.
Only then a submit button will send it to the server.

any idea how should I implement it ?
What component/action should I use ?

any design tip or reference that will help me google further will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

check this website

```
http://elegantcode.com/2009/07/01/jquery-playing-with-select-dropdownlistcombobox/
```

basically using jQuery it's the simplest solution.

1. get  element by it's ID or css
2. get selected value by selector
3. get other  element
4. add value to the new list by appending html code to existing